# Using LAG to Find Previous Value in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to use the LAG function in Oracle to find the previous registration value for donors.

To see my data, I started with this query to find all registrations for the particular donor:

`select registration_id, registration_date from registration r where r.person_id=52503290 order by r.registration_date desc;`

[image: Registrations]

Then I used the `LAG` function to return the previous value along with the most recent value:

`select registration_id as reg_id, registration_date as reg_date,
lag(registration_date,1) over (order by registration_date) as prev_reg_date
from registration
where person_id=52503290
order by registration_date desc;`

And the results are as expected:

[image: LAG Function]

So I thought I should be good to place the `LAG` function within the main query to get the previous value but for some reason, the previous value returns NULL or no value at all.

`SELECT
       P.Person_Id AS Person_ID,
       R.Registration_Date AS Drive_Date,
       LAG(R.Registration_Date,1) OVER (ORDER BY R.REGISTRATION_DATE) AS Previous_Drive_Date,
       P.Abo AS Blood_Type,
       DT.Description AS Donation_Type
FROM
       Person P
       JOIN Registration R ON P.Person_Id = R.Person_Id AND P.First_Name <> 'Pooled' AND P.First_Name <> 'IMPORT'
       LEFT OUTER JOIN Drives DR ON R.Drive_Id = DR.Drive_Id AND DR.Group_Id <> 24999
       LEFT OUTER JOIN Branches B ON R.Branch_Id = B.Branch_Id
       LEFT OUTER JOIN Donor_Group DG on DR.Group_Id = DG.Group_Id
       LEFT OUTER JOIN Donation_Type DT ON R.Donation_Type_Id = DT.DONATION_TYPE_ID
WHERE
       TRUNC(R.Registration_Date) = TRUNC(SYSDATE)-1
       AND R.Person_Id=52503290
ORDER BY
      R.Registration_Date DESC;`

Here is the result set:

[image: Main Query]

Any suggestions on what I am missing here? Or why this query isn't returning the values expected?

Based on @Alex Poole's suggestions, I changed the query to look like:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT
       P.Person_Id AS Person_ID,
       R.Registration_Date AS Drive_Date,
       LAG(R.Registration_Date,1) OVER (partition by p.person_id ORDER BY r.registration_date) AS Previous_Drive_Date,
       P.Abo AS Blood_Type,
       DT.Description AS Donation_Type
FROM
       Person P
       JOIN Registration R ON P.Person_Id = R.Person_Id AND P.First_Name <> 'Pooled' AND P.First_Name <> 'IMPORT'
       LEFT OUTER JOIN Drives DR ON R.Drive_Id = DR.Drive_Id AND DR.Group_Id <> 24999
       LEFT OUTER JOIN Branches B ON R.Branch_Id = B.Branch_Id
       LEFT OUTER JOIN Donor_Group DG on DR.Group_Id = DG.Group_Id
       LEFT OUTER JOIN Donation_Type DT ON R.Donation_Type_Id = DT.DONATION_TYPE_ID
--WHERE R.Person_Id=52503290
)
WHERE TRUNC(Drive_Date) = TRUNC(SYSDATE)-1
ORDER BY Drive_Date DESC;
```

It takes about 85 seconds to pull back the first 30 rows:

[image: Query Results]

My original query (before the `LAG` function was added) took about 2 seconds to pull back approximately 2100 records. But it was nothing but a SELECT with a couple of JOINS and one item in the WHERE clause.

Looking at the record counts, Person has almost 5.5 million records and Registration has 9.1 million records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lag is only applied within the rows that match the `where` clause filter, so you would only see the previous value if that was also yesterday.

You can apply the lag in a subquery, and then filter in an outer query:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT
           P.Person_Id AS Person_ID,
           R.Registration_Date AS Drive_Date,
           LAG(R.Registration_Date,1) OVER (ORDER BY R.REGISTRATION_DATE) AS Previous_Drive_Date,
           P.Abo AS Blood_Type,
           DT.Description AS Donation_Type
    FROM
           Person P
           JOIN Registration R ON P.Person_Id = R.Person_Id AND P.First_Name <> 'Pooled' AND P.First_Name <> 'IMPORT'
           LEFT OUTER JOIN Drives DR ON R.Drive_Id = DR.Drive_Id AND DR.Group_Id <> 24999
           LEFT OUTER JOIN Branches B ON R.Branch_Id = B.Branch_Id
           LEFT OUTER JOIN Donor_Group DG on DR.Group_Id = DG.Group_Id
           LEFT OUTER JOIN Donation_Type DT ON R.Donation_Type_Id = DT.DONATION_TYPE_ID
    WHERE R.Person_Id=52503290
)
WHERE TRUNC(Drive_Date) = TRUNC(SYSDATE)-1
ORDER BY Drive_Date DESC;
```

Comment: Interesting - this works but my query now takes over 2 minutes to run when it was previously running in under 2 seconds - before I used the `LAG` function at all.

Comment: @MISNole - does it help if you make the inner filter on `P.Person_ID`? (The `P.First_Name` filters should be in the where clause too?)

Comment: To be honest, I added the p.person_id='XXX' just to illustrate my data. I do not need that filter at all.  What I'm trying to accomplish is find all drives (events) that happened the previous day - and use the `LAG` function to find the time previous to the prior day.

Comment: @MISNole - your `lag` needs to `partition by P.Person_Id` then. Did your original query take 2 seconds to get all data (e.g. scrolling to the bottom of the results grid), or just to display the first page of results? How much data are you looking at?